# Derived column expression validation error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have write the below code in my derived column expression in ssis package.

Input values as i am receiving from source:-

```
Q:\SOURCE\RV_T\PCL_RVT\RVT_export_all_2011-02-14_08.38.00_Emerald.xlsx
```

i want :- `RVT_export_all_2011-02-14_08.38.00_Emerald.xlsx`

```
Substring(@[User::V_FilePath],LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]) - Charindex("\",Reverse(@[User::V_FilePath]))+2,LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]))
```

its running fine in SSMS but giving below error in SSIS

> Error at DFT - Load Data [Derived Column [8]]: Attempt to parse the
>   expression "Substring(@[User::V_FilePath],LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]) -
>   Charindex("\",Reverse(@[User::V_FilePath]))+2,LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]))"
>   failed.  The token """ at line number "1", character number "68" was
>   not recognized. The expression cannot be parsed because it contains
>   invalid elements at the location specified.
>
> Error at DFT - Load Data [Derived Column [8]]: Cannot parse the
>   expression "Substring(@[User::V_FilePath],LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]) -
>   Charindex("\",Reverse(@[User::V_FilePath]))+2,LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]))".
>   The expression was not valid, or there is an out-of-memory error.
>
> Error at DFT - Load Data [Derived Column [8]]: The expression
>   "Substring(@[User::V_FilePath],LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]) -
>   Charindex("\",Reverse(@[User::V_FilePath]))+2,LEN(@[User::V_FilePath]))"
>   on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
>   Output].Columns[filenaemfrompat]" is not valid.
>
> Error at DFT - Load Data [Derived Column [8]]: Failed to set property
>   "Expression" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
>   Output].Columns[filenaemfrompat]".

---

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Finally after lot of testing i am able to get what i want.

Here is the code i used

```
RIGHT(@[User::V_FilePath],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::V_FilePath]),"\\",1) - 1)
```